# JPA composite Foreign Key part of composite Primary Key unable to find ID

Tags: jpa, key, composite

We have tables,
        'Lin_Code_Groups' with fields,
    Project_ID (PK),
    CG_ID(PK),
    CG_Name

Corresponding  entity class,

```
 public class Lin_Code_Groups implements Serializable {

        @EmbeddedId
        private LinCodeGroupPK pk;  
        private String  CG_name;


    @Embeddable
        public static class LinCodeGroupPK implements Serializable {

            private Integer Project_ID;     

            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            private Integer  CG_ID;
        }   
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "lin_Code_Groups")
            private List<Lin_CG_Params> lin_CG_Params;
    }
```

table Lin_CG_Params with fields,
        Project_ID (PK)..FK to Lin_Code_Groups,
        CG_ID(PK)...FK to Lin_Code_Groups,
        Param_name(PK),
        Param_value

Corresponding  entity class,

```
  public class Lin_CG_Params implements Serializable {
        @EmbeddedId
        private LinCodeGroupParamPK pk;
        private String  Param_value;
    @Embeddable
        public static class LinCodeGroupParamPK implements Serializable {

            private String  Param_name;
            private LinCodeGroupPK linCodeGroupPK;      
        }

        @MapsId("linCodeGroupPK")
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumns( {
                @JoinColumn(name = "Project_ID",referencedColumnName= "Project_ID"),
                @JoinColumn(name = "CG_ID",referencedColumnName= "CG_ID")
            })
           private Lin_Code_Groups lin_Code_Groups;
    }
```

in controller class, i am using JPA's .Save method to save the data in to the tables.

```
@PostMapping(value = {"/hello"}, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
        public ResponseEntity<Object> saveNewCodeGroupsDetails(@RequestBody Lin_Code_Groups objLin_Code_Groups ) {

    respository.save(objLin_Code_Groups);
    }
```

but getting an error 'Unable to find Lin_CG_Params with id Lin_CG_Params.LinCodeGroupParamPK'

Can anyone is please help ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566345/brian-vosburgh , could you please help ?

Comment: I do not see anything obvious. There may be a problem with the JSON mappings. Have you inspected the incoming `objLin_Code_Groups` that is constructed by your JSON mapping tool (probably Jackson?) and made sure everything looks good?

Comment: Thanks Brian for replying..below is the json mapping which i am sending through postman..

Comment: {
   "pk" : 
   {
     "project_ID" :59
   },
   "cg_name" :"CGName1",
    "lin_CG_Params" :[
   {"pk" :
   {,
         "param_name" : "param9",
      "linCodeGroupPK" :
      {
       "project_ID" :59
      }
      
   },
   "param_value" :"Value5"  
    }
    ]
  }

Comment: and the complete error i am getting while saving the data is  "Unable to find Lin_CG_Params with id Lin_CG_Params.LinCodeGroupParamPK(linCodeGroupPK=Lin_Code_Groups.LinCodeGroupPK(Project_ID=59, CG_ID=null), Param_name=param9); nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find Lin_CG_Params with id Lin_CG_Params.LinCodeGroupParamPK(linCodeGroupPK=Lin_Code_Groups.LinCodeGroupPK(Project_ID=59, CG_ID=null), Param_name=param9) "

Comment: I am able to solved the issue related to Id.. i added @Not found ............@OneToMany(mappedBy = "lin_Code_Groups", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private List<Lin_CG_Params> lin_CG_Params;

Comment: But with this change, data is getting saved only in parent table Lin_Code_Groups. Data is not inserted in Lin_CG_Params....why ?

Comment: Hey All, I have solved this issue also... i used  cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER for onetomany and manytoone... and it is inserting data in parent and child tables..  I am so happy  :) :)

Comment: That's great! : ) Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: Hello Brian, I have posted one question , could you please help ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62216709/convert-string-into-json-string